# what is the purpose of this three coils and switching leaver

Tags: voltage, ac

I found a strange device on my junkyard, 
And it seems like it have made to work with three phase.

But there is an strange thing that I could not understand.
That looks like this.

[image]

and that horizontal bar is connected to a leaver that disconnect some electrical
connection.

What I'm asking is , what is the purpose of that? Is this is to balance 3 phases?
if not balance then disconnect it?
There is a big coil there which connect three contracts.

What is the function of these three coils? and this black horizontal bar and switching
leaver?

Comment: Current sensing windings (?).  On the other hand, the wire of the winding looks kind of thick for a sensing coil.

Comment: More pictures might help. If nothing else, maybe a wider shot so we can get the overall look of the thing.

Comment: My first impression was a magnetic protection switch for a 3-phase machine. Not sure about the proper name for them. On overcurrent they switch off the machine. JustJeff is correct, other pictures may help.

Comment: We only guess at best from that picture.  Take a *good* picture or two, with at least one showing the wider device.  Any hint what the device was intended to do would help to.  As it stands now, *it is difficult to tell what is being asked here*.

Answer (score 2):

Those coils are not magnetic or inductive devices, but resistive heating elements. They are insulated from the flat metal strips but in pretty good thermal contact with them - those are bimetallic strips, which bend when heated.  Assuming the strips are about 2" long (with the white insulator about 1" long) it is a single or 3 phase breaker like the one on my milling machine, which dates from the late 1960s or early 1970s.

If so, it provides overcurrent protection for a motor, with a little (thermal) delay to allow for high starting current. If any one of the three overheats, the breaker will trip (in a single phase application, only one is driven) The coil is a solenoid to hold the breaker "on" so that any power interruption will disconnect power to the motor (aka No-Volt-Release or NVR switch). There would usually be a green "Start" button to energise the solenoid and a red "Stop" button to break its power, both on the front of the metal box which used to contain this assembly.

Please do not regard this as definitive without further confirmation : you don't mess with 3 phase lightly...

EDIT: the strip of folded paper is a little scary : someone's attempt to hold the operating bar shut?

Are you in 240V/50Hz land? Any sign of a maker's name?

EDIT: It is almost certainly an AUTO MEMOTA motor starter made by MEM. Mine, though it is only running a single phase motor, also turns out to be 3-phase capable. Note that switching it to 3 phase would involve replacing the 240V coil with a 415V one.

Its trip current is adjustable (without folded paper!) by an adjustment on the other side of the unit (green knob, top right in picture, and scale just to the right of the coil), and there are two recesses on one end (black areas in picture) where the Start and Stop buttons would press, to make/break the solenoid current.

Here it is in its natural habitat.

Note the heater coils are visible on the left.

[image: MEM motor starter]

And a view of the other side, showing current scale, maker's plate, and label confirming coil rating (240V) and other settings.

[image: Starter side view]

In case it's not clear enough how these pics relate to the original, here's one showing the coil assembly from another angle. I'm not going to disassemble the mill just to reproduce the original viewing angle!

[image: Coil assembly]

Comment: Thanks, very helpful , this that green preset is also there in my-one too.

Comment: my switch is 0-8 Amps. Yes I'm from 240V land. Sri Lanka.